# Will adding my own 'textarea' directive overwrite the native Angular directive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm looking to handle all events by textareas and inputs in an angular app.  Normally I'd probably use jQuery to bind a live/on handler to listen for the events I'm after.  But I can't and don't want to use the full jQuery lib, but instead use the native Angular jQuery lite library to accompplish the same effect.

I've tried adding a directive 'textarea' and 'input' that causes my global event to occur.  So essentially I can add a new directive 'textarea' and 'input' to my app, but 'should I'?

Also, I'm not interested in adding a new directive to every input or textarea in the app.  I want to handle this use case globally.  I don't want to have to remember, or have other developers remember to add this directive to all their inputs and textareas, I just want to handle it globally.

But...

Will adding my own 'textarea' or 'input' directive in an Angular app dislodge/overwrite the native Angular textarea directive?

Comment: Any examples of what you're trying to do? There is no AngularJS directive specifically for textareas that I know of (since they match what it used on all `input` fields).

Comment: Well, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input is a directive.  An example: blur out of a textarea or input and update something else -- the scroll position of the window for example.

Comment: In that case you should create your own directive that handles blur (since there is no built-in handler for it on `input` fields) and use that in addition to whatever is already allowed.

Comment: I think what you are getting at is a 'new' directive to add to all of my input and textareas to handle blur -- and that's exactly what I don't want to do, but I should add that to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely define directives with the same name as Angular's built-in directives (or any other module's for that matter). In that case all directives are going to be applied - none is going to be overwritten or "shadowed".

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/U9Bzu/)**. Opening the DevTools' console, you will find the logs proving that both directives with the same name are applied to the element.

---

So, in order to apply textarea-wide behaviour, a `textarea` directive is the way to go.